# To save big files, why use Google Storage rather than Java project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When making a contents-file based bulletin with Java, why it is needed to use Google Storage, a separate storage service rather than just creating a folder within Java project itself?

Is there any file size limit that a Java project can become?

Is there any file size limit of a Java project to be uploaded for Google-App-Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App Engine, the local filesystem that your application is deployed to is not writeable. The flexible environment does allow you to write to a directory on a local disk, but written files are ephemeral, due to the fact that the disk gets initialized on each VM startup, so your files will get deleted on this occasion. You can read more related detail on the "Choosing an App Engine Environment" online documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments).

You can profit from the facilities offered by Compute Engine, if writing to disc is a must. By default, each Compute Engine instance has a single root persistent disk that contains the operating system, as stated on the "Storage Options" [page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/). For more insight, you may implement the [proposed example](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine) from the "Running the Java Bookshelf on Compute Engine" page.

The Compute Engine does not handle scaling up of your applications automatically, so you'll have to take care of it yourself, as suggested in the "Autoscaling Groups of Instances" [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/).

There is a maximum size limit of 5 TB for individual objects stored in Cloud Storage. An application is limited to 10,000 uploaded files per version. Each file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes. You may find related details on the "Quotas | App Engine Documentation | Google Cloud" [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas).